# Variance of sample covariance estimator (without assuming an a-priori distribution)?

Tags: statistical-significance, variance, estimation, covariance

Let $X$ and $Y$ be two random variables (with unknown distributions) that might be correlated or not. Assume that $X$ and $Y$ have finite variances. Also, let $[(X_1,Y_1),...,(X_n,Y_n)]$ be a sample of $n$ observations of $X$ and $Y$.

Now, knowing that...

i) $|\text{cov}(X,Y)| \leq \sqrt{\sigma^2_X\sigma^2_Y}$, with $\sigma^2_X$ and $\sigma^2_Y$ being the variances of $X$ and $Y$, respectively.

ii) the variance of a random variable $z \in [A, B]$ is bounded by $\var(z) \leq (B-A)^2/4$ (eq.1)

Can we then state that...

a) the sample covariance follows $|\widehat{\text{cov}}(X,Y)| \leq \sqrt{\widehat\sigma^2_X\widehat\sigma^2_Y}$, with $\widehat\sigma^2_X$ and $\widehat\sigma^2_Y$ being the sample variances of $X$ and $Y$, respectively?

b) If a) holds, then the variance of the sample covariance is bounded (using the eq.1 above) by $ |  \text{var}[\widehat{\text{cov}}(X,Y)]|  \leq \widehat\sigma^2_X\widehat\sigma^2_Y$? (because the sample covariance estimate is a bounded random variable)

If so, is there any reference where the relations above are shown?

Comment: I think these kinds of applications of probabilistic equations to random samples almost always preserve the original findings. That's because a random sample *is* a probability distribution where each observation has probability frequency $1/n$ it's called the empirical distribution function. Note, however, you can't "pick and choose" which theoretical quantities to replace. e.g., it may not hold that $|cov(X,Y) | \le \hat{\rho} \sqrt{\hat{\sigma}^2_x \hat{\sigma}^2_y}$ in a finite sample, though asymptotically they will.

Comment: I don't understand this concept of a "bound" on the covariance in (i): that is an *equality,* not an inequality! Could you clarify what you are trying to assert in (i) and (a)?

Comment: @whuber, as the covariance can take values between $-\rho\sqrt{\sigma^2_X \sigma^2_Y} \leq cov(X,Y) \geq \rho\sqrt{\sigma^2_X \sigma^2_Y}$, we say that $cov(X,Y)$ is bounded by $\rho\sqrt{\sigma^2_X \sigma^2_Y} \leq cov(X,Y)$.

Comment: I don't follow, because the covariance *always equals* $\rho\sqrt{\sigma_X^2\sigma_Y^2}.$

Comment: Oh, I see. You're right. Sorry, I mistyped the equations above and forgot to include the magnitude and get rid of the correlation coefficient. I'll fix it.

Comment: @whuber, Thanks. I corrected the OP. The idea in a nutshell is that, if the sample covariance is a bounded random variable, and if we can calculate these bounds as in a), then using eq.1 we could define bounds for the variance of the sample covariance.

Comment: In (a), since the sample covariance (by the *definition* of the sample correlation coefficient) *equals* the sample correlation times the sample SDs, there's little to say.  It's unclear what you're trying to ask in (b), because the left hand side is a theoretical value (computed over all possible samples) while the right hand side is the result of a single sample.  It's possible, for instance, that one of $\hat\sigma_X$ or $\hat\sigma_Y$ in a sample could be zero, but obviously that doesn't imply the left hand side must be zero!

Comment: BTW, the (usual) sample covariance estimate is not necessarily a bounded random variable.  Under the assumptions you have made, its value could be anything with arbitrarily high probability, depending on the underlying distribution.

Comment: @whuber Thanks for the explanation. I got your point about using the sample variances in the right-hand side is not exactly right, but in many text books when approximating variance for estimators, it is suggested to use the sample variance (or a bootstrap-approximation of it) as a guess for the (true) theoretical variance. I know the sample variance does not necessarily equal the theoretical one, but that is what I get to try to calculate the bounds for variance of the sample covariance estimator.

Comment: About the point of the sample covariance estimator not being necessarily bounded, that is the point!  If it were bounded and if we knew its upper and lower bounds, we could calculate the bound for the variance of the sample covariance estimator using eq. 1. Got it?

Comment: To estimate the variance of the usual estimator of sample variance, you would use the sample *fourth* moments, not the sample variance (ditto for covariances).  Usually, knowledge of hard bounds on an estimator won't do you much good except for truly tiny sample sizes.  If you're interested in learning more about the variances of variance estimators, then it would work better to ask about that issue directly in your question.

Comment: @whuber, I know that to estimate the var of the sample var we use 4th moments, but that's nothing to do w/ my question. I asked about trying to estimate $bounds$ for the variance of the cov. estimator starting from the idea that the sample covariance might be bounded. This is pretty easy to get from my question TBH, AdamO got it immediately, even when the notation was messed up. I don't know if you usually go to conferences, have this kind of discussion w/ other peers, or gave lectures to undergrads before, but we researchers don't usually go too deep in formalism in this kind of conversion

Comment: I don't see how it's easy, given there are no bounds and given how your question is predicated on things that aren't true (or are irrelevant).  The values you give for the "bounds" are themselves *random variables.* That functions quite differently from fixed bounds like the $A$ and $B$ you cite.